# Is it possible to kill Cicero before the DarkBrotherhood questline?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know you can find Cicero outside a farm on a road with the night mothers coffin, but is it possible to kill him?
And if so would that screw up the DB questline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **No**

Before The [Cure for Madness](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Cure_for_Madness) Cicero is unkillable, as he's been designated as [Essential NPC](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Essential_NPCs).

Comment: Doesn't stop you from beating the **** out of him over and over though... He deserves it, trust me.

Comment: @JClaspill He's a good companion tho? And he never did anything wrong so why would you kill him? He's just a little bit annoying.

Comment: Cicero is my favorite character in the game for some reason.

Comment: @RafaelCelerier I said beat him, not kill him. From how he acts, I'd assume he'd almost enjoy the beatings.

Answer (score 3):

No, he is essential at that point and cannot be killed.